# Why use max and min macro in __global__ kernel of CUDA not giving correct answer?

Tags: c++, cuda, macros

I was trying to write a simple CUDA function to blur images. I use myself defined max and min macro as

```
#define min(a, b) ((float)a > (float)b)? (float)b: (float)a
#define max(a, b) ((float)a > (float)b)? (float)a: (float)b
```

The part of `__global__` kernel is:

```
   float norm;
   float sum = 0;// when filter exceed border, norm will affect!
   int center = radius * filterWidth + radius;
   int imgx = 0, imgy = 0;
   for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
   {
       for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
       {
           imgx = min(max(x + absolute_image_position_x, 0), numCols-1);
           //imgx = min(numCols - 1, imgx);
           imgy = min(max(y + absolute_image_position_y, 0), numRows -1);
           //imgy = min(numRows-1, imgy);
           sum += (float) inputChannel[(imgy*numCols) + imgx] * filter[center + (y*filterWidth) + x];
       }
   }

   outputChannel[pos] = (unsigned char) sum;
```

But the min and max can not give correct answer when I tried to debug. For example, min(max(10,0),100) will give 100.0f!
I did not check each step why it was wrong. But later I changed to cuda math functions, the results became right.
Anyone has idea. Is there any restriction in use of macro in CUDA kernel?

Comment: Why do you even want to use macros, when you state yourself that your kernel works correctly when you use functions provided by CUDA?

Comment: Actually it is for curiosity:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the `(float)` to clear the clutter, your macros look like this:

```
#define min(a, b) (a > b)? b: a
#define max(a, b) (a > b)? a: b
```

And example use (simplifying a few variable names):

```
imgx = min(max(x + aipx, 0), nc-1);
```

will expand to:

```
imgx = ((x + aipx > 0)? x + aipx: 0 > nc-1)? nc-1: (x + aipx > 0)? x + aipx: 0;
```

Perhaps that is getting parsed incorrectly? Try putting extra parens around the use of your macros' arguments:

```
#define min(a, b) ((a) > (b))? (b): (a)
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b))? (a): (b)
```

Comment: Oops. Yes! You are right. I tested. Thanks a lot. I always use macro min max before but never met this issue. Maybe I never use them in one expression

Comment: Some people will say macros are evil; I say they should be used infrequently and very carefully, but used when appropriate. That being said, it is a generally good practice to never use macro arguments raw but to surround them with `()` so as to avoid any unwanted effects of tokens unintentionally butting up against one another with a new, undesired meaning.